# Fisher information of sample

Tags: fisher-information

Definition of single random variable Fisher Information is $$I(\theta)=E_\theta((\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} ln f(x,\theta))^2)$$
and we get that
$$E_\theta((\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} ln f(x,\theta))^2)=-E_\theta(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}ln f(x,\theta))$$
If we have $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ iid random variables the definition of Information is
$$E_\theta((\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} ln f(x_i;\theta))^2)$$
and my question is how to proof that
$$E_\theta((\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} ln f(x_i;\theta))^2)=-E_\theta(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2} \sum_{i=1}^n ln f(x_i,\theta))$$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take square inside each Xi, you will get the result. Here is the proof.
[image: (image with formulas)]